# C#: Class return value - or is there a better way?

Tags: c#

I created a class that had one member of type List. I could then add to this using `ClassNameInstance.Add()`.

We are now using some code from a third-party that will automatically use any class I create and its values. Except lists. It only returns the first element in the list.

What I need is a comma-separated version returned instead for this third-parties code to use.  Now I could just append the Strings to a String member, but this doesn't look as nice as the .Add() method.

So I wanted to create my own Class that I could have an Add() method for but could access its single value like so:

```
MyClass1.Add("Test1");
MyClass1.Add("Test2");

Console.WriteLine(MyClass2);
```

The output I would like would be `Test1, Test2`.  I hope this makes sense!

UPDATE1:

Seems the above may not have been clear.

```
public class MyClass1
{
    ????
}

public class MyClass2
{
    MyClass1 mc1 { get; set; }
    String name { get; set; }
}
```

The third party code will use MyClass2 and its assigned values. When I used List instead of MyClass1 I only get the first value in the list, but need a CSV list as a String returned.

```
MyClass2 mc2 = new MyClass2();

mc2.mc1.Add("Test1");
mc2.mc1.Add("Test2");

Console.WriteLine(mc2.mc1) should output -> Test1, Test2
```

Hope that clears things up some more!

Thanks everyone! :)

UPDATE2:

It seems everyone is suggesting the same thing - use ToString().

Unfortunately, the third-party code will look at my class and determines the members type and value automatically. This means that I am not able to pass the code the value that would be returned by calling ToString().

I kind of need the add/remove functionality of a List<> but when used its value returns as a single CSV string.

Comment: The answers so far seem to answer the second part of your question, but I must admit I can't quite understand how that combines with the first part - is your third party code also performing a ToString() on your class?

Comment: @Benjol:

I'm not sure exactly what it does as I haven't been given the sourcecode (although I could get it).

I actually want my class to be used within a second class. This second class would be used with the 3rd-party code so I cann't use ToString() unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really the answer I wanted, but it seems that I couldn't do what I wanted.

In the class where I wanted to have my second class as a member, I made that member a String so the third-party code would work as I wanted.

I created a second class that had a `List<String>` as a public member and then a Method called `.ToCSV()` to output the list as a csv string. I added a `.Add()` method to add the strings to the list to save having to go `Class1.Class2.Add()`.

Then just before the third-party code would use my class, I do:

```
MyClass1.MyString = MyClass2.ToCSV();
```

Thus giving me basically what I wanted in a round about way!!

Thanks for everyone's input and help!

Neil

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure that you need an extra class here:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("Test1");
list.Add("Test2");
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", list.ToArray());
```

You *could* wrap this behaviour in a class just to get it automatically invoked on `ToString`:

```
public sealed class StringJoiningList
{
    private readonly List<string> list = new List<string>();

    public void Add(string item)
    {
        list.Add(item);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Join(", ", list.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Now that's assuming you just want a `List<string>` - it also doesn't let you access the items *other* than by the `ToString()` method. All of that is fixable of course, if you could give more information. You *could* even just derive from `List<T>`:

```
public class StringJoiningList<T> : List<T>
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Join(", ", this.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());
    }
}
```

I'm not entirely sure I like the idea, but it depends on what you need to do...

Comment: I'm not able to use ToString as the third-party code is just passed a Class name (i.e. MyClass2 in the edited original question above) and works out its type and makes use of its value.

Comment: If you use either of the classes above as `MyClass1`, your test case will work because `Console.WriteLine` will call `ToString` itself. If your third party class doesn't, we'll need to know what it *does* do.

Comment: I tried the classes above and they did indeed work with Console.WriteLine, but sadly with my third party code it doesn't work.

Comment: @neildeadman: In that case you need to find out more about what they're doing.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of easy options would be to override the ToString() method of your class (so that when it is used in this context it returns a comma-delimited list of items) or you can provide a property that flattens the list.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the ToString method.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is probably to inherit from the StringCollection class and just override ToString. Otherwise this class already has everything you are asking about.

```
public class MyClass : System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        var c = new string[this.Count];
        this.CopyTo(c,0);
        return string.Join(",", c);

    }
}
```

Then you can use it just like you were trying to before. No need to get fancy with generics for this simple usage.

Edit:

Classes themselves don't have a return value, so the 3rd party code must be reading properties. You should be able to override ToString() as described above then expose a property that returns the ToString(). That would probably make the string value visible to the 3rd party code

```
public class MyClass : System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection
{
    public string MyValue
    {
        get { return this.ToString(); }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        var c = new string[this.Count];
        this.CopyTo(c,0);
        return string.Join(",", c);

    }
}
```

Comment: This would work except when the third-party code is called, I pass it an instance of my class that contains this class. It won't ever use ToString as it processes the class automatically.

I have edited my original question with a better description.

Comment: I've adjusted the answer above. I still think this mechanism can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an extension I wrote to join the items in an IEnumerable<T>

```
public static string Join<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, 
                             string separator, Func<T, object> selector)
{
    if (null == separator)
        throw new ArgumentException("separator");
    if (null == selector)
        throw new ArgumentException("selector");

    Func func = item =>
    {
        var @object = selector(item);
        return (null != @object) ? @object.ToString() : string.Empty;
    };
    return string.Join(separator, collection.Select(func).ToArray());
}
```

It can be used like this:

```
List<Person> list = new List<Person>()
{
    new Person() { FirstName = "Magic", LastName = "Johnson" },
    new Person() { FirstName = "Michael", LastName = "Jordon" },
    new Person() { FirstName = "Larry", LastName = "Bird" }
};

var value = list.Join(", ", p => p.FirstName);

// value is "Magic, Michael, Larry"
```